# Microsoft Excel to extract date from another string

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

Hi Need help in extracting date with the below values

/test/extractDate/agenda/**2016/06**/09/href.txt||/test/extractDate/agenda/2016/06/09/abc.txt

I need to extract first occurrence of date and month. From the above i need **2016/06** only.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume you have a list like this you need the date from? How is it laid out, will the year/month *always* be the fourth and fifth items?  Do note that you can do Text to Column, use `/` as a delimiter. This will put each value in between `/` into their own cell, on the same row.

Comment: Would anything else in the text ever have something similar to a year? i.e. 65201654321/test/extract?  Will your years always start 20XX?  Will there be some 19XX dates?  Will this run long enough to get to 202X dates?

Comment: Is it always separated with parallel bars in the middle like that?

Comment: @BruceWayne Thanks for the comments yes it is always 4th and 5th element

Comment: @cricketbird thanks for the comments. No other value have such format.

Comment: @Brian No some times only first string will be available. like this /test/extractDate/agenda/2016/06/09/href.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",CHAR(1),4))+1,7)
```

Comment: Nice! I was playing around and was trying to get something shorter.  What's the `Char(1)` doing?

Comment: @BruceWayne It substitutes a space (start of heading) for the fourth occurrence of `/` (Ascii value for 1). No credit here, though. I had to research it first.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have no digits before date, use MID(A1,SEARCH(2,A1,1),7)

Answer (score 0):

This should work, assuming your info. is in `A1`:

`=MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","\",4),"/",";",5),SEARCH("\",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","\",4),"/",";",5))+1,7)`

Edit: Ah, boo. It looks like my formula is a more convoluted way of doing @Brian's formula. His is better :)